# How to get trailer & playlist from home page with youtube API

Tags: php, api, youtube

I have to get trailer and playlist which are on home page of my channel.
I tried to use Activities with home parameter but nothing that I get back permit me to get playlist or trailer.

Here's some of my relevant code:

```
  $oYoutubeService = new Google_Service_YouTube($oGoogle);
  $playlists_optParams = array('home' => true);
  $stream = $oYoutubeService->activities->listActivities('snippet', $playlists_optParams);
  var_dump($stream);
```

but in this result I haven't any trailer or playlist.

If my goal is not clear, for example on the channel `youtube.com/user/youtubenation`I would like to get the trailer ("Nicole Richie keeps...") and playlist after ("YouTube Nation Playlist", "True Facts About Ze Frank"...)

Is there a simple way to get back the trailer, playlist or video from channel's home page ?

Thanks

Comment: Can we see your code so we know exactly what you tried?

Comment: I tried :
>_$oYoutubeService = new Google_Service_YouTube($oGoogle);
            $playlists_optParams = array('home' => true);
            $stream = $oYoutubeService->activities->listActivities('snippet', $playlists_optParams);

            var_dump($stream);_

but in this result I haven't trailer or playlist.

If my demand is not clear, for example on this channel :
http://www.youtube.com/user/youtubenation

The goal will be to get trailer ("Nicole Richie keeps...") and playlist after ("YouTube Nation Playlist", "True Facts About Ze Frank"...)

Comment: I edited your post to include the additional details, it's easier to read up there. Always include sample code, an example use case, and your intended result (as well as how the actual results differ) in the original post if possible.

Answer (score 2):

I built this messy code snippet that grabs a youtube channel page and strips out the video trailer ID, and then embeds the video. It was for another project, and could use some tidying up.

```
<?php
// Fetch YouTube channel page.
//  ------REPLACE THE ADDRESS INSIDE THE QUOTES WITH THE DESIRED YOUTUBE CHANNEL------
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.youtube.com/user/YOUR_YOUTUBE_CHANNEL/');
// Identifies what text we are searching for, then returns the cursor position in the file where that text string begins.
$videoID = 'data-video-id';
$pos = stripos($html, $videoID);
// Remove all of the content before the data-video-id, and remove the new first 15 characters of the file, which would now be-> data-video-id:"
$str2 = substr($html, $pos);
$str3 = substr($str2, 15);
// Grab the first 11 characters, cause YouTube video IDs are 11 characters long.
$id = substr($str3, 0,11);
// Create a string with the youtube video URL, using the ID variable.
$ytlink = 'http://www.youtube.com/v/' . $id;
//Determine whether user is mobile, and if they are, don't size the video.
$isMobile = (bool) strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'Mobile');
if ($isMobile) {
    $size = " ";
} else {
//These values can be changed to your own needs.
    $size = "width=425 height=350";
}           
// Embed the YouTube video.
echo '<object ' . $size . ' data="' . $ytlink . '"type="application/x-shockwave-flash">';
echo '<param name="src" value="' . $ytlink . '" /></object>';
?>
```